# document.writeln() is breaking my jQuery partial update. How can I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm having trouble writing the HTML below to the page after an asynchronous get request. The HTML is provided by a 3rd party charting service, so I can't modify it myself, other than when I get the response after the `$.get()`.

I asked the following question a while ago: [Why is this HTML causing the page to go blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217146/why-is-this-html-causing-the-page-to-go-blank). The answer was:

> "document.write after the page has
>   fully rendered ... will create a new
>   document"

As such, would it be possible for me to replace the `document.writeln()` function with a jQuery function which will include the HTML in thd DOM? If so, what is it I need to do?

is it a case of find and replace? Or will it even work? Is there another way to solve this issue?

```
<!-- Chart by Corda Enterprise Server (PopChart, Highwire) Version 7.2.3.3177 (Jun 11, 2008) .NET Embedder 7.1.0.2116 -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    var put2087644907Props;
    var put1181439927Props;
    var put433403842Props;

    function getImageMap1325059360() {
        put2087644907Props = new PopUpProperties;
        put2087644907Props.width = 400;
        // lots more of these properties being set 


        // not sure exactly, but this has something to do with providing hover-over functionality
        document.writeln('<map name="imVB_2wFC_WSdl" id="imVB_2wFC_WSdl"><area shape="poly" coords="540,52,547,52,547,59,540,59,540,52" onmouseover="return showPopUp ? showPopUp(put2087644907Props, \'VB_2wFC_WSdl\', \'Schroder All Mats Idx Lnkd Bd I Acc 2.58%\', 543, 49) : false;"/> /* big long string */ onmouseover="return hidePopUp ? hidePopUp() : false;"/></map>');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ie-sv-corda72:2001/?jsPopUp"></scr'+'ipt>');

    if(document.layers) getImageMap1325059360();

</script>
<img id="VB_2wFC_WSdl" name="VB_2wFC_WSdl" width="570" height="243" style="border: 0;"
    usemap="#imVB_2wFC_WSdl" src="http://ie-sv-corda72:2001/?@_CPRVB_2wFC_WSdl" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (!document.layers) getImageMap1325059360();
</script>
<noscript>
    <map name="imVB_2wFC_WSdl" id="imVB_2wFC_WSdl">
        <area shape="poly" coords="540,52,547,52,547,59,540,59,540,52" alt="Schroder All Mats Idx Lnkd Bd I Acc 2.58%" />
        <area shape="poly" coords="497,41,504,41,504,48,497,48,497,41" alt="Schroder All Mats Idx Lnkd Bd I Acc 3.27%" />
        <%--lots of these area elements which gives the chart hover-text functionality--%>
    </map>
</noscript>

<!-- Corda Enterprise Server (PopChart, Highwire) Version 7.2.3.3177 (Jun 11, 2008) .NET Embedder 7.1.0.2116 by corda.com -->
```

For reference, this is the code that does the get:

```
$.get(url, {}, function (result) {

    $('#FactsheetTabs .tab_container').fadeOut(100, function () {
        $('#tabs')
            .append(result) // this fails in FireFox & chrome, but not IE... why?!
            .fadeIn(100);
    });
}, 'html');
```

If I edit the response to comment out the `document.writeln()` code like the following, it works:

```
$.get(url, {}, function (result) {

    $('#FactsheetTabs .tab_container').fadeOut(100, function () {
        result = result.replace("document.writeln", "//document.writeln");
        result = result.replace("document.writeln", "//document.writeln");
        $('#tabs')
            .append(result) // this works now...
            .fadeIn(100);
    });
}, 'html');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `document.writeln()` function with one of your own that will safely append the html to the DOM without breaking it.  For example:

```
document.writeln = function (html) {
    $(document.body).append(html);
}
```

The other option is close to your replace method but, instead of adding comment delimiters, replace `document.write` with your own method:

```
result = result.replace(/document\.writeln/g, "$(document.body).append");
```

Comment: @DaveDev: before your ajax call should do it.

Comment: ... provided that `document.expando = false;` has not previously been called in IE. Unlikely, I admit.

Comment: I would rather replace the calls to `document.writeln` than override it. Modifying native objects isn't a good idea: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: @casablanca: that's not quite the same thing, it doesn't really apply here.  Kangax is talking about extension via prototypes with the main issues being naming collisions and poor browser support.  In this case, we're aware of the naming collision - we know the purpose of `document.writeln` it's our intent to stop it doing what it's doing.  The only issue is if you wanted to use `document.open`, followed by `document.writeln`, but there's rarely a valid use case for that.

Comment: @Andy E: Actually it does, the key point being that "Host objects have no rules". The browser is free to do anything with such objects, including completely ignoring your request to override `writeln`.

Comment: @casablanca: maybe so, but the vendors have all reached a consensus on this -- none of them are stupid enough to risk breaking existing scripts out there by disallowing the overriding of DOM properties.  All I'm saying is that your argument doesn't really hold water in the *real world*.

Comment: @Andy E: That's true, I don't debate that. But I would choose a better option when available.